# Android fragment is not displayed, even after inflating it

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio, fragment

I state I am a beginner in app developing, expecially with fragments.
I am working on an app project in AndroidStudio; I am trying to make an Homepage that shows up some information like online status, messages received and so on.
For every information, I have tried to associate a fragment but this is not shown, even though there are no errors in the code.
I am using the 4.2 version and I write the code in Java; I have tried everything but I am done with ideas. 
Any suggestions? Am I missing something?[I was doing something like the image shown in this link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sQsJH.png).
I will post the code below: 

This is the **MainActivity**:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        BottomNavigationView buttonNV= findViewById(R.id.menu);
        buttonNV.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(navListener);


        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.online_frame,new OnlineStatusFragment()).commit();

    }
```

The **online_fragment** (layout of my fragment):

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="203dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="42dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="42dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="36dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="27dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="27dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="277dp"
        android:background="@drawable/border_tv"
        android:text="SEI ONLINE/TESTING"
        app:drawableRightCompat="@drawable/settings_icon" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

The **activity_main.xml**:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:background="@color/background">

    <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="55dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:id="@+id/online_frame">

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/online_fragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:name="com.example.progetto_lso_b.OnlineStatusFragment"
            tools:layout="@layout/online_fragment" />

    </FrameLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_menu"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
        android:id="@+id/menu"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

This is the **OnlineStatusFragment.java**:

```
public class OnlineStatusFragment extends Fragment {

    public OnlineStatusFragment() {}

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate il layout per questo fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.online_fragment, container, false);
    }
}
```

Comment: Just change Framelayout height.
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"

Comment: And the way you are doing, it will add 2 Online fragments. 1 from activity code(using getSupportFragmentManager)  & 1 from xml code ( <fragment> tag)

Comment: so, should I delete fragment from XML code? @KishanMaurya

Comment: It's your choice. Either will work. I will prefer to use the Main activity one. It will give more control to fragment like adding/replacing

Comment: I tried to do what you were saying on the first comment but it did work well. I am trying to make 3 "boxes" that will contain 3 different fragments (each one doing a different job); doing as you said will put only one box on the screen; maybe should I resize the layout of the fragment?

Comment: In that case, you have to create 3 containers ie. FrameLayout for 3 fragments and add fragment in respective containers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what I did wrong in my code.
I set the width and the height of my TextViews in a wrong way; in point of fact, I had to set these data with `match_parent` and  `wrap_content` respectively.
Furthemore I deleted the `<fragment>` in the file **activity_main.xml** (just like someone commented before) because it would have "duplicated" the fragment.
This is the code in **online_fragment.xml** :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".OnlineStatusFragment">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/online_status"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
        android:text="Sei online/sei offline"
        android:drawableRight="@drawable/settings_icon"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

And this is the **activity_main.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:background="@color/background">

    <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="55dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:id="@+id/online_frame">
    </FrameLayout>
    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_menu"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
        android:id="@+id/menu"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Thanks to all for helping me!